# How do I setup this (Mock setup)

Tags: nunit, mocking

I have the following test:

```
        var home = new DummyPageModel { Parent = null };
        var pageRepository = new Mock<IPageRepository>();
        pageRepository.Setup(x => x.SingleOrDefault<IPageModel>(page => page.Parent == null)).Returns(home);
```

but when I run this test I get a System.NotSupportedException : Expression page => (page.Parent == null) is not supported?

The implementation of SingleOrDefault looks like this:

```
    public T SingleOrDefault<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : IPageModel {
        return _documentSession.Query<T>().SingleOrDefault(predicate);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it like this, pageRepository.Setup(x => x.SingleOrDefault(It.Is>(page => home.Parent == null))).Returns(home);